# How to skip certain bytes at the begining of a binary file in Gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Say I have a binary file which has the following format: 4*sizeof(double), 4*sizeof(size_t), (Ny*Nx)*dizeof(double).

The first 4 doubles and the 4 size_ts are metainformation about the file. The rest is data I want to plot with gnuplot.

Right now I have to convert the file to another one without the header to plot using the command:

```
plot "convertedfile.data" binary format='%double' array=(Ny, Nx) u 1 w image
```

**Q:** Is there any way to tell gnuplot to ignore the starting `N` bytes of the binary file and then plot the rest as if its a matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can skip some bytes at the beginning with **skip**

```
plot "convertedfile.data" binary skip=16 format='%double' array=(Ny, Nx) u 1 w image
```

will skip the first 16 bytes of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably to write a small C program to strip off the metainfomation and write the remaining data to a new file.

Comment: That's what I do now, but it'll be better if gnuplot could just ignore a few bytes in the begining of the binary file. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it's the most accurate from the ones this question received :-(